# How do I setup per-assembly resharper settings

Tags: c#, resharper

I work in a codebase where for historic reasons not all projects have identical coding conventions. In fact, within a single .sln I have projects requiring different naming conventions.

Is there a way to have resharper use different settings based on which project the file I'm editing lives in?

Comment: I would suggest asking on the JetBrains forums: http://devnet.jetbrains.net/community/resharper/resharper_eap

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out the [Resharper Settings Manager](http://rsm.codeplex.com/) tool

You'll need to first install the [ReSharper Power Toys](http://resharperpowertoys.codeplex.com/) to use it.

Comment: looks like that's as good as it gets.  It only does settings per solution though :(.  I'll wait to see if more answers come in, otherwise will accept this one. thnx.

Comment: Ah, interesting. I was interpreting this line literally: "You have to work on different projects with different code styles, so you have to be able to reconfigure Resharper Inspection Severity (Highlighting) Options, Code Clean-Up options and etc. for each project individually." Apparently it's not referring to actual project files... Bummer!

Answer (score 8):

Since ReSharper 6.1 **you can finally have per project settings**!
Basically, all you need to do is to create a file named `<project file name>.DotSettings`, e.g. `MyUnitTest.csproj.DotSettings`.

See [this blog post](http://blogs.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2012/01/per-project-settings-or-how-to-have-different-naming-styles-for-my-test-project/) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Resharper now supports applying different settings to different Solutions from Resharper 6.1.  See this blog post for further details http://blogs.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2011/11/resharper-settings-in-61/

However, from the looks of it, you cannot yet apply different settings to different projects within a solution.  This is a feature I would very much welcome too!

Answer (score 0):

Additionally (to the other answers) when using SVN the "*.sln.DotSettings" files are changed every time a different machine opens the solution. To combat this set the read-only attribute on the DotSettings files, after checking out from the repository.