# Make resharper ignore code suggestions for specific projects

Tags: .net, resharper

Is there way to make ReSharper ignore code suggestions in specifi projects?

In my test project I like to use method naming as Should_return_True() instead of the suggested ShouldReturnTrue() because i think it easier to read and to highlight the most important words.

In my production code I still would like to get the suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Check our Resharper Settings Manager
http://rsm.codeplex.com/

[How do I setup per-assembly resharper settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3923568/how-do-i-setup-per-assembly-resharper-settings)

Comment: According to the question you linked to, this only gives you per-solution settings, not per-project like this question is asking for.

Comment: The site says "per project", but I don't think they're using the word 'project' to mean VS project. So it appears you are correct, Joe.